# How to trim first N elements from in List in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, trim, concatenation

How to write a prolog program to trim first N elements from a List in prolog using conc operation.

```
trim(L1,N,L2) which is true if L2 contains the first N elements of L1
```

Can somebody please help me.

Here is my answer and is it correct?

```
trim(L1, N, L2):- conc(L2,T,L1), length(L2,N),length(L1,N2), N2>= N
```

Comment: Try using `append/3`.

Comment: @Tudor Can u please mention the answer. I am confused with how to include N

Comment: Try mixing `length/2` and `append/3` to express the `trim/3` relation.

Comment: @Tudor- I am a newbie to prolog. Can u please mention the answer. I  cannot think of a way to use length operation too to this.

Comment: Read the comments by @TudorBerariu. Then, read the documentation of your Prolog on the predicates he mentioned and figure out what they do. Then, try to solve your problem. After you have some code that you have written and debugged and you still don't know what to do, edit your question to show your effort and you might get an answer.

Comment: Ok, I added my answer. Is it correct?

Comment: @false u re correct. That should give 'false'. So how to add that scenario as an statement? 
trim(L1, N, L2):- conc(L2,T,L1), length(L2,N), length(L1,N2), N2>= N 
Is this correct

Answer (score 5):

The easy solution uses `length/2` and `append/3`, along these lines:

```
trim(L,N,S) :-    % to trim N elements from a list
  length(P,N) ,   % - generate an unbound prefix list of the desired length
  append(P,S,L) . % - and use append/3 to get the desired suffix.
```

Note that the order doesn't really matter. This will work, too:

```
trim(L,N,S) :-    % to trim N elements from a list
  append(P,S,L) , % - split L into a prefix and suffix
  length(P,N) .   % - succeed if the prefix is of the desired length
```

I imagine that your instructor wants you to figure out a/the recursive solution. One might note that the algorithm for trimming items from the left end of a list is pretty simple:

- Walk the list until you've visited `N` elements.
- Once you've done that, whatever is left over is the desired result.

That leads to a simple solution:

```
trim( L     , 0 , L ) .  % Trimming zero elements from a list yields the original, unchanged list
trim( [H|T] , N , R ) :- % Otherwise,
  N > 0 ,                % - assuming N is greater than zero
  N1 is N-1 ,            % - we decrement N
  trim( T , N1 , R )     % - and recurse down, discarding the head of the list.
  .                      % That's about all there is too it.
```

If you wanted to be pedantic, one could enforce a constraint that the list should actually be a list (or at least list-like), something like:

```
trim( []    , 0 , []    ) .  % Trimming zero elements from the empty list yields the empty list
trim( [H|T] , 0 , [H|T] ) .  % Trimming zero elements from a non-empty list yields the same list  
trim( [H|T] , N , R     ) :- % Otherwise,
  N > 0 ,                    % - given that N is greater than zero
  N1 is N-1 ,                % - we decrement N
  trim( T , N1 , R )         % - and recurse down, discarding the head of the list.
  .                          % That's about all there is to it.
```

Note that that something like

```
trim( [a,b,c] , 5 , R ) .
```

will fail: See if you can figure out how to make something like the above succeed, with `R = []`. Hint: it's not difficult.

**Edited to Note:** If you actually want to take the 1st N elements of the list, that's no more difficult:

```
prefix_of(L,N,P) :-
  append(P,_,L) ,
  length(P,N)
  .
```

Or, rolling your own, you could do something like:

```
prefix_of( _      , 0 , []     ) .  % once we've counted down to zero, close the result list and succeed.
prefix_of( [X|Xs] , N , [X|Ys] ) :- % otherwise,
  N > 1 ,                           % - given that N is greater than zero,
  N1 is N-1 ,                       % - decrement N
  prefix_of( Xs , N1 , Ys )         % - and recurse down, with X prepended to the resullt list.
  .                                 % Again, that's about all there is to it.
```

Comment: Arg3 shall contain "the first N elements". Of course that is counter intuitive and does not correspond to the title.

Comment: *Note that the order doesn't really matter* it does matter.  Both versions possess different termination behavior.

Comment: Beside different termination behaviour, the two versions of `trim/3` also imply different numbers of logical inferences. Performance is often ignored in logic programming, but it's still an important aspect. For both reasons (termination and efficiency), the `length`, `append` order should be preferred.

Comment: Thanx Nicholas. U should correct all your answers so that the result shall contain "the first N elements" and then I can mark ur answer as right.  In your first answers u have taken the rest of a list after removing first N elements and that is not what asked for.

Comment: Au contraire, Your question's title, "How to trim first N elements from in List in prolog" says that you want to *trim* the first elements from the list. The definition of the verb *to trim* is "`to cut (something) off something else : to remove (something) by cutting.`"